# LibGDX class does not appear to call a superclass constructor, how is this possible?

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to extend the built in libgdx class GLFrameBuffer but don't understand what i am supposed to write for a constructor.

GLFrameBuffer already has another subclass, FrameBuffer, which uses the folowing constructors, the last of which is the subject of confusion.

```
FrameBuffer () {}

protected FrameBuffer (GLFrameBufferBuilder<? extends GLFrameBuffer<Texture>> bufferBuilder) {
    super(bufferBuilder);
}

public FrameBuffer (Pixmap.Format format, int width, int height, boolean hasDepth) {
    this(format, width, height, hasDepth, false);
}
public FrameBuffer (Pixmap.Format format, int width, int height, boolean hasDepth, boolean hasStencil) {
    FrameBufferBuilder frameBufferBuilder = new FrameBufferBuilder(width, height);
    frameBufferBuilder.addBasicColorTextureAttachment(format);
    if (hasDepth) frameBufferBuilder.addBasicDepthRenderBuffer();
    if (hasStencil) frameBufferBuilder.addBasicStencilRenderBuffer();
    this.bufferBuilder = frameBufferBuilder;

    build();
}
```

Note there is no call to a superclass constructor, and its superclass does not have a (visible) no-argument constructor. Why is this allowed? Both classes DO have private no-argument constructors with no code. If i exactly copy the FrameBuffer class and rename it i get a message saying i must explicity invoke another constructor.

edit: libgdx version 1.9.8

Comment: Which version of libgdx are you working with? You are right it doesn't sound right. My guess is something got mixed up when you looked at the source code.

Comment: Well. Currently, it [does](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/FrameBuffer.java) look like that. However, its superclass [_does_](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/GLFrameBuffer.java) have a visible no-argument constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you call private constructors aren't actually private.

They are default constructors, their visibility level is `default` not `private`. This is the access modifier that's applied when you don't specify an access modifier (hence the name default)

In java anything with the default access modifier can be accessed by other classes in the same package.

And these classes are both in the same package, `com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils`.

The `FrameBuffer ()`constructor is in fact calling it's no argument `super` constructor.

Comment: I see. Is there any way to extend the GLFrameBuffer class that wouldn't subvert the intended usage?

Comment: If your subclass won't be instantiated with the default constructor, you can just skip it. Otherwise you will have to decide what superclass constructor to invoke and what values to pass based on your subclass and it's functionality.